# How to write a function so as to not repeat code

Tags: jquery, function, events

I want to avoid repeating myself.

The following code uses a conditional statement to check for the presence of an element. When that element is not detected, a unique bit of code is inserted using `.html()`

Whatever the conditional element evaluates to, the same event trigger is called. This is less than optimal.

How would one optimize this code so as to not write it twice?

```
// Trigger for showing participants
        var triggerDiv = $('span.registered');
        var participantsTable = $('#participants');

        // if participants table has no descendants
        if( !participantsTable.has('tbody').length ){

            console.log('has NOT registrants');

            triggerDiv.on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
                participantsTable.html('<tr><td>No one has yet to register</td></tr>').toggle();
            });

        } else {

            console.log('has registrants');

            triggerDiv.on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
                participantsTable.toggle();
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the common part of the code to after the `if/else` and just set a function variable inside the `if/else`.

```
    // Trigger for showing participants
    var triggerDiv = $('span.registered');
    var participantsTable = $('#participants');
    var triggerFn;

    // if participants table has no descendants
    if( !participantsTable.has('tbody').length ){

        console.log('has NOT registrants');

        triggerFn = function(){
            participantsTable.html('<tr><td>No one has yet to register</td></tr>').toggle();
        };

    } else {

        console.log('has registrants');

        triggerFn = function(){
            participantsTable.toggle();
        };

    }
    triggerDiv.on('mouseover mouseout', triggerFn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I came up with. jfriend00's answer got my mind going..

```
        /**
        * If there are no registered user, display a unique message
        * Otherwise display registered users
        */
        // Trigger for showing songcircle participants
        var triggerDiv = $('span.registered');
        var participantsTable = $('#participants');

        hasNotParticipantsMsg = (participantsTable.has('tbody').length) ? false : $('<tr><td>No one has yet to register</td></tr>');

        triggerDiv.on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
            if(hasNotParticipantsMsg){
                participantsTable.html(hasNotParticipantsMsg).toggle();
            } else {
                participantsTable.toggle();
            }
        });
```